# Trying to install polymer-quill via bower

Tags: polymer, bower, polyfills, quill

New to bower and web components.   I'm trying to install the [polymer-quill library](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/chuckh/polymer-quill) with bower.

```
npm install -g bower
mkdir polymerquill
cd polymerquill
bower install --save polymer-quill
```

Now I have a full `bower_components` directory.  I make an `index.html` file and add the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer-quill/polymer-quill.html">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PolyQuill</h1>
    <style is="custom-style">
      polymer-quill.full {
        --polymer-quill-editor-max-height: 300px;
        --polymer-quill-editor-min-height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Full Toolbar, Show Results, Max Height (300px), Min Height (100px), Save as Deltas, Save every 1 second</h2>
    <polymer-quill content='{"ops":[{"insert":"Hello World! - Store as Delta"},{"attributes":{"header":2},"insert":"\n"}]}'
      class='full'
      store-as="delta"
      save-interval="1000"
      toolbar-type="full"
      show-results>
    </polymer-quill>
    <h2>Standard Toolbar, Hide Results, Default height (100px), Save as HTML, Save every 2 seconds</h2>
    <polymer-quill content="<h2>Hello World! - Store as HTML</h2>" store-as="html"></polymer-quill>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it in Chrome, however, I only see the `h2`'s.  The `polymer-quill` elements don't render.  What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this element currently only works in Polymer's **shady DOM** (see issue [here](https://github.com/chuckh/polymer-quill/issues/10)).

If you're using Polymer 1.0, declare shady DOM by adding the following script in your `index.html`: ([reference](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings))

```
<script>
  /* this script must run before Polymer is imported */
  window.Polymer = {
    dom: 'shadow',
    lazyRegister: true
  };
</script>
```

---

If you're using Polymer 2.0, when importing webcomponents just add the `shadydom` attribute as follows:

```
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" shadydom></script>
```

Comment: I did this in Elm, this video helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMsovr-AQ34